# Installing .net framework v4.30319

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to install .net framework v4.30319 for web service. When run this command in cmd:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.reggis.exe -i
```

it creates administrative rights issues. But I am already logged in with an administrator account.  How can I resolve the administrative issues?

Comment: What do you mean with "administrative rights issues"?

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, could you post that as well? Also, I'm assuming you are running aspnet_regiis.exe and not aspnet.reggis.exe.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on cmd and click "Run as Administrator"

Typically windows does not open programs by default as an administrator, even if your account has the type of administrator.  In the properties of a `.exe`, you can set to always run as an administrator.